# Angular 5 w/ Angular Material 2 - Optimal Way to load a background?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm wondering what's the best way to add a background to the app.component of my Angular 5 Application using Angular Material 2. I've seen a few previous stack overflow posts regarding this in previous versions of Angular and tried using them but to no avail.

So I was looking to see what is the currently reccomended way of doing this in Angular 5 w/ Angular Material 2.

Thank you

Path to the image from this component "../../images/background.jpg"

```
<div [class.app-dark-theme]="true">
    <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen class="sidenav-container">
        <!-- The Navigation button at the top of the application -->
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">

            <div class="select-discord">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> Discord
            </div>

            <div class="select-twitch">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> Twitch
            </div>

            <div class="select-twitter">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> Twitter
            </div>

            <div class="select-youtube">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></mat-icon> YouTube
            </div>

        </mat-toolbar>

        <img class="img-responsive" src="../../images/background.jpg">

        <!-- Main content of the website -->
        <div class="app-content">
            <mat-card>
                text here
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Which element do you want to apply a background to?

Comment: Is there something wrong using the `background-image` css property?

Comment: @WebDevBooster I want it to be completely in the background so i can have a mild opacity on the navbar and everything else.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm just trying to find the reccomended way of doing it in Angular 5 with Material 2 that's all. I know how to do this in your standard pure html and css website but i prefer learning the reccomended ways of doing things :)

Comment: Both of these build on HTML and CSS. Material-2 specifically tells you to style using CSS. What makes you think this *isn't* the recommended way?

Comment: Because seeing as it's a framework for readability and other purposes there are generally design guidelines to follow. Rather than just brute forcing solutions.

Comment: ... No. It's really not. You're still supposed to style your components in css or scss or sass or whatever flavor of style sheet your preferred setup uses. The Angular framework gives you *functionality*. The material libraries give you *components* (and guidelines to follow). Your css lets you apply styling and customize the look of all of them.

Comment: Alright, Thank you. Still new to Web Dev mainly a desktop application developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way of adding a background would be to add an id to your container and give that id the following css rule:

```
#my-bg {
    background: url('../../images/background.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: alright, wasn't too sure if there was something angular specific to do here rather than just pure css/ html